# Why does my object remain null while it has a value?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, nullreferenceexception

i try to show the number vote
in my itemDetails page I receive my data from the page items all my data is readable yet (string Titre, string Description, int Vote) when i click on my button to acces on the items details page I receive the error object null, when is trying to read the INT. I tried to go into try.parse or a multitude of solution to the conversion but I can not find not good writing

[Image](https://gyazo.com/d5a589efeca122906a15934e807e8dbb)

Thank you

```
FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();

public ItemDetailsPage(string Titre, string Description, int Vote)
{       
    InitializeComponent();
    MyTitre.Text = Titre;           
    MyDescription.Text = Description;
    MyVote.Text = Vote.ToString();
}
```

---

```
   // ITEM PAGE
    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var allIdeas = await firebaseHelper.GetAllIdeas();
        listIdeas.ItemsSource = allIdeas;
    }
    //    BOUTTON VERS PAGE DETAILS

    private async void OnItemSelected(Object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var details = e.Item as ItemsModel;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailsPage(
            details.Titre, 
            details.Description , 
            details.Vote));
    }
---------------------------
 <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                   x:Name=" MyVote" d:Name="Name!"
                   BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
```

Comment: Can you show how you call `ItemDetailsPage`? Also where exactly do you get the NullReferenceException?

Comment: my null reference appear when i add the line MyVote.Text = Vote.ToString(); if not is work perfect

Comment: And which object is null? `MyVote` or `Vote`?

Comment: i dont know and i dont how to know i have just a crash with a message null reference. MyVote.Text  is a like my reedit post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                   x:Name=" MyVote" d:Name="Name!"
                   BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
```

Perhaps removing the space in front of the MyVote might fix the problem.

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                   x:Name="MyVote" d:Name="Name!"
                   BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
```

Comment: OOOOh my god I am on this F.... error for 48 hours and I have not even slept because of this ... thank you thank you thank you you save my long-awaited night of sleep.